# SQL Update with distinct and max Select

Tags: vba, sql-update, max, inner-join, distinct

I tried for too long and my head hurts too much to not ask this here...

```
str_SQL = "UPDATE tbl_Main " & _
"INNER JOIN " & _
"(SELECT MAX([Kursdatum]) " & _
"FROM tbl_Fremdwaehrungskurse) " & _
"ON tbl_Main.[Fremdwaehrung_ISO_CODE] = tbl_Fremdwaehrungskurse.[Fremdwaehrung] " & _
"SET " & _
"tbl_Main.[Wechselkurs_aktuell] = tbl_Fremdwaehrungskurse.[Wechselkurs_aktuell], " & _
"tbl_Main.[Kursdatum_aktuell] = tbl_Fremdwaehrungskurse.[Kursdatum];"
```

What it should do... Update tbl_Main with only the most recent Dates from tbl_Fremdwaehrungskurse.[Wechselkurs_aktuell] from distinct Values tbl_Fremdwaehrungskurse.[Fremdwaehrung]

Trying to get this done in VBA, tables are in Access 2010

Comment: Show your table structure. What is it doing now?

Comment: Nothing because there's a sql error...